# Can Oracle JDBC driver cache sequence values

Tags: oracle, caching, jdbc, driver, sequence

Oracle sequence values can be cached on the database side through use of the 'Cache' option when creating sequences. For example

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
  CACHE 1000;
```

will cache up to 1000 values for performance.

My question is whether these values can be cached in the the oracle drivers.

In my application I want to pull back a range of sequence values but don't want to have to go back to the database for each new value. I know Hibernate has similar functionality but I've been unable to find out exactly how it's accomplished.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not reserve one batch of numbers in one  session (if I understood correctly). Setting correct cache value would very likely make this acceptable from performance perspective. 
If you still insist you can can create similar functionality yourself - to be able to reserve at once one range of numbers

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by igr it seems that the oracle drivers cannot cache sequence values in the java layer.

However, I have got round this by setting a large increment on the sequence and generating key values myself. The increment for a sequence can be set as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name 
INCREMENT BY $increment;
```

In my application, every time `sequence.nextval` is executed I assume that the previous `$increment` values are reserved, and can be used as unique key values. This means that the database is hit once for every  `$increment` key values that are generated.

So lets say for example that `$increment=5000`, and we have a starting sequence value of 1. When `sequence.nextval` is run for the first time the sequence value is incremented to 5001. I then assume that the values `2..5001` are reserved. Then the 5000 values are used in the application (In my use case, they are used for table primary keys), as soon as they are all used up `sequence.nextval` is run again to reserve another 5000 values, and the process repeated.

The only real downside I can see to this approach is that there is a tiny risk from someone running ddl to modify the `$increment` between the time the nextval is run and the `$increment` is used to generate values. Given this is very unlikely, and in my case the ddl will not be updated at runtime, the solution was acceptable.

I realise this doesn't directly answer the question I posed but hopefully it'll be useful to someone else.

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: so this is a hilo algorithm , but a very fancy flavour ?